# Ĉu ekzistas lernolibroj por lerni la Anglan pere de Esperanto?

Tags: learning, books

Laŭ mia scio ekzistas lernmetodoj por Esperanto en preskaŭ ĉiu lingvo, kaj multaj homoj lernas Esperanton ĉar ili ne bone sukcesis pri la angla. Ankaŭ mi scias ke eblas lerni diversajn lingvojn pere de Esperanto. Sed ĉu ekzistas tiu eblo por lerni la anglan, kaj se jes, kiuj metodoj aŭ referenco-libroj ekzistas?

Answer (score 4):

Mi ne pensas ke tia libro ekzistas, malĝoje.

La retpaĝo de Universala Esperanto-Asocio havas [katalogon](http://katalogo.uea.org) de Esperantaj Libroj. En tiu katalogo estas la kategorio "lerniloj alilingvaj". Tio devus enhavi libron por lerni la anglan, sed ĝi ne ekzistas.

Answer (score 2):

Ĝuste tian (retan) ‘libron’ mi estas kreanta: [Enciklopedia Vortaro de la Merk-Angla](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/). Mi ligas al anglalingvaj fontoj, sed ankaŭ al Vikivortaro. La ‘nesto’ estas Esperantlingva, kaj mi ofte donas klarigojn kaj komentojn en Esperanto pri diversaj punktoj en la angla. Jen la adreso de la (daŭre konstruata) reta verko: http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/

Comment: La paĝo probable perdiĝis?

Answer (score 0):

La ejo ‘Ekonomia Bulteno pri Usono’, rekte kaj libere atingebla, havas strikte paralelajn tekstojn angla – Esperanta. Jen la ligilo al ĝi:

https://ekonomiabultenopriusono.com/

La paralela formato de la traduko havas du celojn:

1. faciligi lingve-kontroli la tradukon;
   kaj
2. esti rimedo por lernantoj de la angla.